# Use a separate desktop on a external monitor?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

For my workflow, I like to have multiple desktops. One for a browser, another for some sort of editor and another for a full screen terminal.

When I connect an external monitor though. It doesn't work quite how I would like.

If I place a window on my external monitor (like my music player or something). Then I switch desktops to view my editor. My external monitor also changes desktops.

Also if I use expose, My external monitor also goes into expose mode.

Kinda annoying.

Is there anyway (possibly using 3rd party tools). To keep the two monitors seperate an have two dedicated work areas/desktops?

Comment: At first glance this question appears to be off topic but I suggest it is relevant to those of us performing software development on OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I have this same issue.  I like to keep different IDE's open on each desktop and use my external monitor as a 'common' desktop to hold reference material, etc.

I have been able to simulate it by setting certain applications to 'All desktops' but it would be great if it was window based and automatic.  That way one could drag a window to the external monitor and have it stick to all desktops and drag it back and have it stick to the current desktop.