# If there OS level limitation that prevents mapping virtual desktop to real monitor in dual monitor scenario?

Tags: winapi, multiple-monitors, virtual-desktop

What is the API to work with virtual desktops on Windows and why it doesn't allow to map virtual desktop to multiple monitors?

Virtual desktop software for Windows doesn't allow to exclusively bind second monitor to certain virtual desktop. I tried `desktops`, `mDesktop`, `Finestra`, `VirtuaWin` and `WindowsPager`. Is it operating system limitation or poor hardware architecture? Is that limitation appears on Linux and OS X too?

It could be that people just don't need this functionality, but a few voted questions prove otherwise:

https://superuser.com/questions/234243/how-to-map-a-virtual-desktop-to-a-monitor-in-a-multiple-monitor-setup

[Use a separate desktop on a external monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126868/use-a-separate-desktop-on-a-external-monitor)

Comment: Still does not make it about programming. Edit: I see your edit now :) Seems fine, but will probably be closed.

Comment: @leppie, I should probably mention that I am interested to send a patch to existing projects if I know how to fix that. Maybe I shoud ask another one with [autohotkey] tag for `mDesktop` and [c] for all others.

Comment: Windows does not have a concept of virtual desktops. The only distinction is between the *input desktop* and all other [desktops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573.aspx). You should clarify your question and use established terms to describe your problem.

Comment: @linspectable, thanks for clarification. I'd like accept this as an proper answer before moving further as this misconception can be quite common for users not familiar with Windows API.